# Help with Summation and Probability Notation

Tags: probability, summation

[image]

Can someone tell me why the value of Q here ranges from 0 to 1? I am new to this notation. I understand that it is a summation from 0 to *i*. But how does summing *i* no. of probabilities together bounds the value of Q to range from 0 to 1. Wouldn't it require some sort of averaging?

Edit (Added Context, I don't think reading this is of much help):
[image]

Comment: Given disjoint events $A,B$ in some sample space, you have $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.  Further, recall that $0\leq \Pr(E)\leq 1$ for all events (*including those events who can be written as the union of other events*).  (*Note: in general the probability of the union will not be equal to the sum of the probabilities when $A,B$ are not necessarily disjoint, but rather $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$*)

Comment: My best guess, reading the passage, is that they intend each of these $N_i$ to be disjoint events.  Whether that makes sense depends on context, which this question is lacking.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hey, I have added more content from the page, but I am not sure if that's going to help. I guess the original writing lacks enough detail to clarify the mathematical model the author is going for here?